# Как реализовать в Woocommerce Wordpress функционал построения меню из категорий сайта

Tags: wordpress

Подскажите плагин или код реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Например так можно:

```
  $args = array(
        'show_option_all'    => '',
        'show_option_none'   => __('No categories'), 
        'style'              => 'list', //Стиль  
        'show_count'         => 1,
        'hide_empty'         => 0, 
        'hierarchical'       => true,
        'title_li'           => '',
        'echo'               => 1,
        'depth'              => 0,
        'current_category'   => 0,
        'pad_counts'         => 0,
        'taxonomy'           => 'product_cat', //category
        'walker'             => 'Walker_Category',
        'hide_title_if_empty' => false,
        'separator'          => '<br />',
    );

    ?>                 

  <ul class="category-menu">
    <h3 class="sidebar-title">Категории</h3>  
    <?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
  </ul>
```

Подробное описание функции  [wp_list_categories](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_categories)

> Стилизованный результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо. Я тут порылся еще в инете,нашел статью  https://clicknathan.com/web-design/automatically-create-wordpress-navigation-menu-items/  , не могли бы вы подсказать что нужно добавить что бы работала иерархия категорий выводяться все категории и внутренние и внешние в одну полосу? спасибо

Comment: @Dimarik Не совсем понял что вам нужно.  Если вы хотите отключить иерархию есть параметр **'hierarchical' => true / false**  Показывать категории как дерево.  Показывать вложенные (дочерние категории), как вложенный список  .                                                                                             https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_list_categories#hierarchical-logicheskij

Comment: И есть параметр **'style' => 'list'**  - Стиль вывода списка

Comment: Спасибо.сейчас буду пробовать.

Comment: Будут вопросы пишите, постораюсь ответить.

Comment: Дело в том что подрубрики выводит как верхние категории,главные рубрики. https://i.imgur.com/YIDyLzu.jpg    не могли бы вы подсказать что нужно добавить в код из этой статьи https://clicknathan.com/web-design/automatically-create-wordpress-navigation-menu-items/   что бы корректно отображалось меню,подрубрики были спрятаны в  рубрики верхнего уровня https://i.imgur.com/ED8Axjp.jpg

Comment: 'hierarchical'       => true,  не помагает выводит все равно всё на одном уровне без вложений

Comment: Закомментируйте ваш код, скопируйте код выше, подкорректируйте строку  'taxonomy' => 'product_cat', //category  под ваш запрос.  И вы увидите вложенность как в панели администратора.  Вам нужно будет только настроить отображение меню через CSS.

Comment: @Dimarik Какова ваша задачи? Что вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Уже все работает,просто нужно вложенность добавить неужели в том коде из сайта не получиться добавить вложенность?

Comment: Попробуйте поменять значение  'menu-item-depth' => 1 на 0

Comment: Нет что то не помагает,хорошо попробую ваш вариант прикрутить.

Comment: @Dimarik  Получилось?